# Access to the model in Django view.py to output a file

Tags: python, django, csv

I would like to output a bed file by accessing to one of the model and print out the whole column.

```
def ctb(request):
    # Create the HttpResponse object with the appropriate CSV header.
    response = HttpResponse(mimetype='text/bed')
    response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somefilename.bed"'

    writer = csv.writer(response, delimiter='   ')
    for row in targetedgene:
        writer.writerow([row.1 , row.2])

    return response
```

Error states that:

> Exception Value:  invalid syntax

Here's my model

```
class targetedgene(models.Model):
    cellline = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    targetedgenes = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    fullnamegene = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    chromlocation = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    startlocation = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    endlocation = models.IntegerField(max_length=50)
    regulated = models.CharField(max_length=10)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.targetedgenes+ "  .  " + self.fullnamegene + "  .  " + self.regulated
```

How can I write each row? How can I access to the model in View.py?
Is it possible that I can output each row in one individual file? I hope to combine chromlocation, startlocation, endlocation and targetedgenes columns into the bed file.

Comment: What is `targetedgene`?

Comment: that is my model. class targetedgene(models.Model)

Comment: ok, include your model definition to the question, thanks.

Comment: I managed to solve it by referencing to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10455753/django-how-to-output-csv-with-model-containing-many-to-many-field?rq=1.